# Implement ac-dc converter for low frequency and very low voltage without external powering?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, low-power, low-voltage

Iam using a basic cascade voltage multiplier to boost and rectify the 0.3v ac signal. The circuit rectifies but the boost is very less. So I thought of using LTC3105 after this stage to get a regulated dc output voltage. Problem in simulation is it is taking really long time to simulate moreover LTC3105 is not boosting up below 0.5 v but according to datasheet LTC3105 starts up at 0.25 v. Can you please help me out with this?

Implement ac-dc converter for low frequency and very low voltage without external powering? - ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Implement_ac-dc_converter_for_low_frequency_and_very_low_voltage_without_external_powering [accessed Apr 21, 2016].[image]

Comment: Do you want to use 0.3 V AC source as a power source? What current do you intend to take from it?

Comment: RMS, peak or p-p?

Answer (score 1):

This circuit as it is will NOT work because the forward voltage drop for the 1N5817 is about 0.55 volts at its lowest. Unless you use external power, the suggestion of a step-transformer by @Bruce Abbott is a good idea.
 You have almost no options at this low of a voltage. Use a tiny audio transformer and see if the speaker output (measures a couple of ohms dc) can be your signal input, the measure the secondary windings (many ohms dc) and see what kind of boost you will get, and is it enough. Increase C6-C9 to double or triple their present values.
 You are working on the fringes here.
The 140NEX transformer should work fine. It could increase the input signal a lot, but your voltage multiplier is going to load it down a lot. The big issue is if this gives you enough to run the circuit. 
Now it comes down to how strong your raw 0.3vac is (how much current can it supply). If it can maintain 100 mVAC under load I think this circuit may work. It depends on the LTC3105 start-up current.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott what do you mean by that

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me to use a audio transformer. I am planning to use 140NEX transformer. http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/140NEX.pdf        I tried doing the simulation with the following values. DC primary resistance 5.30 ohms and secondary resistance 116.5 ohms and inductance of 326mH and 90.36H. I am getting a output value of 5 v. Can you please let me know if the specifications I used in the simulation are suitable or not?

Comment: Secondary inductance should be 9.3H. You should get ~5V out of the rectifier but only with very light loading. To improve output voltage under load you need a larger transformer with lower resistances. You could also use a higher turns ratio (eg. 1:10) and get 5V with only 2 diodes.

Comment: My question is that is it possible to use 140NEX in this situation? And can I use 140NEX to implement  the circuit practically. the secondary inductance for 140NEX is 90.36.

Comment: I am not going to use the LTC3105 if the basic circuit with the transformer and the voltage multiplier circuit gives a considerable output. My ac source  resistance is 5 ohms. I have run the simulation with the specifications of 140NEX. Please have a look at the simulation, I will add my answer below and let me know if the specifications are ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

The LTC3105 is a complex IC which can take a while to simulate, particularly at startup. In your circuit the high ripple and voltage drop under load stops the LTC3105 from starting up properly, so simulation is very slow.

The basic problem with your circuit is that the rectifier is very inefficient at such low voltage. Putting a booster after it doesn't help because the rectifier can't supply enough current to run it properly.

There are two reasons why the rectifier doesn't work well.

1. Coupling capacitor values are too low, causing excessive AC voltage drop. You should increase the values of C8 and C9 to 1000uF or higher. Connecting C8 directly to V2 instead of in series with C9 will also help.
2. Your AC input is 0.3V *peak*. Even at low current the 1N5817 has a voltage drop of about 0.2V, so most of the input voltage is wasted. Schottky diodes have lower voltage drop than most other types, so to get much lower voltage drop you might have to use active rectification (transistors switched on and off in sync with the AC waveform).

Instead of trying to rectify the low voltage directly you could step it up with a transformer. This may be quite bulky at 20Hz, but a lot simpler than an active rectifier.

Comment: Can you please suggest some step up transformers which can work in this range available in market?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me to use  transformer. I am planning to use 140NEX transformer. http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/140NEX.pdf        I tried doing the simulation with the following values. DC primary resistance 5.30 ohms and secondary resistance 116.5 ohms and inductance of 326mH and 90.36H. I am getting a output value of 5 v. Can you please let me know if the specifications I used in the simulation are suitable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the simulation question, adding a large resistance to any nodes that have only caps on them can help speed up the simulation. In addition there are some simulation options that allow you to avoid certain numerical solution techniques. I havent used these options much so I cant add anymore to that.

Also, the more stable a circuit is the more easily it can be simulated, so just the fact that it is taking a long time to simulate can mean there are some problems. Then again simulating an isolated flyback converter usually takes longer when there is no resistive path to ground and that doesnt have much to do with the stability of the circuit. Well...anyways. Normally though this idea of a stable circuit or a properly functioning circuit does lead to faster simulations.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I have used 140NEX transformer. I tried doing the simulation with the following values. DC primary resistance 5.30 ohms and secondary resistance 116.5 ohms and inductance of (326mH and 9.36H).Parallel resistances (primary-2.83k and secondary-79.0k).
 I am getting a output value of about 5 v. Can you please let me know if the specifications I used in the simulation are suitable or not?